# PostGIS, closest point to another point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, knn

I have two tables: *point1* and *point2*. For each point from table `point1`, I want to find the closest point from table `point2`.

For example: For point with `id=1` from table `point1`, the closest point from table `point2` has id (?? I want to get that `id`).

I tried to use `ST_ClosestPoint` but but it did not work properly. My code:

```sql
SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(pont2.geom, (SELECT point1.geomxy WHERE point1.id=1))
FROM pint2, point1
```

Comment: You misspelled "point2" two different ways in the provided SQL. What error message did you receive, and how did it "not work properly"? Please [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 14):

This is referred to as (spatial) *(K)NN* search; the most performant approach is a `LATERAL` sub-query in conjunction with the index driven `<->` operator:

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.id,
       -- a.geom / b.geom
FROM   <points1> AS pt1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id
  FROM   <points2>
  ORDER BY
         geom <-> a.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS b
;
```

---

I recommend to [further read](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knn+postgis) on multiple topics concerning *(K)NN* queries, to understand **`LATERAL` queries, distances and index usage**.

**Related:**

- [Nearest Neighbor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/nearest-neighbor/287810#287810)
- [PostGIS: ST_ClosestPoint join error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352900/postgis-st-closestpoint-join-error/352905#352905)
- [Optimizing my script; taking too long; distance between many objects PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268025/optimizing-my-script-taking-too-long-distance-between-many-objects-postgis/268168#268168)
- [Speedup function to calculate distance from centroid of building to river segment in PostgreSQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337896/speedup-function-to-calculate-distance-from-centroid-of-building-to-river-segmen/337939#337939)